# Access Denied for getting AWS S3 bucket content with HTTP request C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Endpoints.StandardLibrary;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WebDataExporter.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ScraperController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ScraperController> _logger;

        private readonly string accessKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
        private readonly string secretKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");

        private string endpointUrl = @"https://www.example.com/";
        private IAmazonS3 s3Client;

        public ScraperController(ILogger<ScraperController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, new AmazonS3Config
            {
                ServiceURL = endpointUrl,
                RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUNorth1
            });
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetS3Object")]
        public async Task<S3Object> Get()
        {
            const string BUCKET_NAME = "web-scraper";

            // Retrieve an object from the S3 bucket
            ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
            {
                BucketName = BUCKET_NAME
            };

            ListObjectsV2Response response = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);

            S3Object[] objectsArray = response.S3Objects.ToArray();
            S3Object latestObject = objectsArray.Aggregate((j, k) => k.LastModified > j.LastModified ? k : j);

            var getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = BUCKET_NAME,
                Key = latestObject.Key
            };

            using (var res = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(getObjectRequest))
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(res.ResponseStream))
            {
                var content = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }

            return latestObject;
        }
    }
}
```

This project is an ASP.NET Web API, excluding some models. (As a newbie to AWS, my code is the result of trial and error. Please avoid criticizing it as I know it can be enhanced in various ways.)

What I'm really wondering is why do I get an `Access Denied` response, even after setting everything to public in AWS?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I tried playing around with the settings in AWS and I also tried using different methods for getting content. For example: the `ListObjectsV2Request` was successful, however `GetObjectAsync` was not.

Comment: Does the IAM role have correct permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The Public setting you are referring to is the ability to access the S3 bucket via http/s to download files. This does **not** include the AWS API, which is used by the C# code.

The AWS API needs correct IAM Permissions to access S3.

Comment: Forgot to add this to the original post, but I do have a IAM user, with the AmazonS3FullAccess policy. And I am using its access keys

Comment: Please update the question with the details, fix the image and include the actual error report. If you have S3FullAccess you can’t have an Access Denied. There must be an error in your configuration.